# Get the window that the user is interacting with when two instances of the app are running side by side

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an app that supports multi-window on iPad.
I'm trying to get the current active window that the user is currently interacting with when two instances of the app are running side by side. I've tried many different solutions, but nothing returns the correct window.

For example, running the code below when two instances are running side by side returns two windows instead of the lastly interacted with window.

```
UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
.filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
.map({$0 as UIWindowScene})
.compactMap({$0})
.map({$0.windows.map({$0})})
.flatMap({$0})
.filter({$0.isKeyWindow})
```

returns this:

```
▿ 2 elements
  - 0 : <UIWindow: 0x7ff39f8101c0; frame = (0 0; 678 1024); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000015f1b60>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x6000015f1830>>
  - 1 : <UIWindow: 0x7ff39fa16200; frame = (0 0; 678 1024); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000015b5c50>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x6000015bef10>>
```

The ask is to get the window that the user is interacting with when two instances of the app are running side by side.

Comment: Why do you need to know ? You could use a delegate method that could be called by window code to notify sharedAoplucation .